# Bitbake - use different toolchain in a recipe

Tags: bitbake, u-boot, openembedded

I am trying to write a bitbake recipe to compile U-Boot. We're pulling the U-Boot source from a repo where we've made our own modifications, and our target is different of that from the rest of the layer the recipe is a part of.

Before trying to add this recipe, I built our current image and generated an SDK, which contains the cross-compiler I need. However, I'd like to be able to compile this without depending on the SDK.

The underlying script for building U-Boot calls the cross-compiler directly, so I think I only need to update `PATH` within the recipe. But I can't find the cross-compiler in the project anywhere. Does anyone know where `populate-sdk` gets it's set of cross-compilers from so that I can add it to `PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

Yocto passes a bunch of variables among which there is CC to the build scripts, so if it's not hardcoded anywhere in those scripts, you shouldn't have anything to do.
There are already plethora of U-Boot recipes so take inspiration from those. Try to find one for the same major version as yours. There might be some patches required for the sources but wrt to the cross-compiler, Yocto should be handling it just fine if your source code is following best practices.

As for "our target is different of that from the rest of the layer the recipe is a part of." I don't understand what you meant exactly.

Comment: I think U-Boot we're targeting for a device separate from the one that runs the OS. But they're being bundled together in the same deliverable. So most of our layers are built with one compiler, whereas U-Boot we use something different. Running bitbake's `-populate_sdk` gives me a toolchain with the compiler I need, but I don't know where it's coming from.